# scaling down the view of the content inside an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an iframe on a page where I display my own HTML content.

I need to scale down the display of this content, **but not by CSS's zoom definition**, more like zooming with the CTRL+[mouse wheel] in the browser.

For example, if you hold down the CTRL key and scroll down with your mouse wheel, even in the current page you're reading now, you'll notice that everything displays smaller but kept in proportion and scale. The same goes for scrolling up, of course.

I need to do that with JS/JQ/CSS for the content of the iframe, as mentioned.

Just to be clear - not to have the effect of being able to scale down or up, but to get the final result - displaying the page scaled down.

I should mention that when I change the "zoom" CSS definition of the elements in the content, everything does display smaller, but not kept in proportion and thus messing up the page layout and structure.

Comment: *"everything does display smaller, but not kept in proportion and thus messing up the page layout and structure"* , with all do respect (really!), then you should really redo your coding.

Comment: Try adding `perspective (1px)` to scale, check [this article](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/transforms-cause-font-smoothing-weirdness-in-webkit/).

Comment: @LinkinTED I can understand why you say that and maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question about this... When I say here "my own HTML content", I'm actually talking about an HTML code that comes from another site, which I grab on server side. I have no control over this HTML code, therefore cannot make it any different and must do everything "externally" to it. I can add my own code to it, though. So i'm looking for something I can add to this code in order to get the desired results as described in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest your add the css-rule `transform: scale(0.5);` to your iframe or the content you want to resize. The example scales your content to 50% size.